# Does JMESPath support something like a spread operator?

Tags: jmespath, grafana-loki, promtail

Is it possible to convert this JSON:

```json
{ "message": "Hello!", "contextMap": { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, ...otherInContextMap }, ...someOther }
```

(where keys of `contextMap` are not known) into the following JSON:

```json
{ "message": "Hello!", "foo": 1, "bar": 2, ...otherInContextMap  }
```

using JMESPath?

(Context: I want to scrape Java logs with `contextMap` using Promtail and store `message` together with members of `contextMap` to Loki.)

**EDIT:** I need to explicitly pick `message` and members of `contextMap`. (There are some other unknown/dynamic members `...someOther` in JSON.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge a [basic query](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#basic-expressions) selecting the content of `contextMap` along with a [multiselect hash](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#multiselect) for the message.

So, given the query:

```
merge({message: message}, contextMap)
```

On your given input, it would yield the expected:

```json
{
  "message": "Hello!",
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you!

It seems that `merge` will fail, if `contextMap` is not present (at least in go-jmespath: `interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not map[string]interface {}`). Is it possible to tweak merge not to fail?

Comment: Odd, merging `null` (which is what a basic query on a field that does not exists should do) to an object should work. Does, doing an ugly thing like `merge({message: message}, to_array(@)[?contextMap].contextMap | [0])` fixes it?

Comment: Another thing to try could be: `merge({message: message}, {contextMap: contextMap}.contextMap)`

Comment: No:( See https://go.dev/play/p/eeAEThlGGrk

Comment: Final solution is ```merge({message: message},  not_null(contextMap, `{}`))```.

Comment: For the sake of the community, would you please report that issue on their tracker: https://github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath/issues. Expected behaviour, is that ```merge(`{"a": 1}`, null)``` should yield `{"a": 1}`